# Raku: return Type

Tags: raku

I want to write a function returning an array whose all subarrays must have a length of two.
For example return will be `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`.

I define:

(1) `subset TArray of Array where { .all ~~ subset :: where [Int, Int] }`;

and

```
sub fcn(Int $n) of TArray is export(:fcn) {
    [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
}
```

I find (1) over-complicated. Is there something simpler?

Answer (score 7):

## Stepping back first

```
subset TArray of Array where { .all ~~ subset :: where [Int, Int] };
```

> Is there something simpler?

Before we go there, let's step back. Even ignoring your code's "overly-complicated" nature based on just looking at it, it's also potentially problematic and complicated for various reasons that may *not* be so obvious. I'll highlight three:

- This `subset` will accept an `Array` containing `Array`s, with each of those arrays containing two `Int`s. But it doesn't mandate an `Array[Array[Int]]`. The outer `Array`'s *type* may be just a generic `Array`, rather than being an `Array[Array]` let lone an `Array[Array[Int]]`. Indeed it *will* be unless you deliberately introduce strongly typed values. I will cover strong typing in the last section of this answer.
- What about an empty `Array`? Your `subset` will accept that. Is that your intent? If not, what about requiring *at least one pair* of `Int`s?
- The outer `where` clause uses a common Raku idiom of the form `.all ~~ ...`, with a [junction](https://docs.raku.org/type/Junction) on the left hand side of the [`~~` smart match operator](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-smartmatch_operator). Astonishingly, per [an issue I just filed](https://github.com/Raku/problem-solving/issues/297), this may be a problem. What alternatives are there?

## Starting simple

Raku does a decent job of keeping simple things simple. If we put aside any artificial desire for strong typing, and focus on simple tools for tightening code up, a simple subset I would have suggested in the past would be:

```
subset TArray where .all == 2; # BAD despite being idiomatic???
```

This has all of the problems your original code has, plus in addition it accepts data that has non-integers where integers belong.

But it does have the redeeming qualities that it does a useful check (that the inner arrays each have two elements) and it's significantly simpler than your code.

Now I've reminded myself that I need to view `.all` on the left hand side of `~~` as possibly a problem, I'll instead write it as:

```
subset TArray where 2 == .all; # Potentially the new idiomatic.
```

This version reads more poorly, but, while readability is important, basic correctness is *more* important.

## Still fairly simple, and less problems

Here are two variants I came up with:

```
subset TArray where all .map: * ~~ (Int,Int);
subset TArray where .elems == .grep: (Int,Int);
```

These both avoid the junction/smartmatch problem. (The first `where` expression does have a junction to the left of a smart match, but it's not an example of the problem.)

The second version isn't so obviously correct (think of it as checking that the count of subarrays is the same as the count of subarrays that match `(Int,Int)`) but it nicely lends itself to fixing the problem of matching if there are zero subarrays, if that were to need fixing:

```
subset TArray where 0 < .elems == .grep: (Int,Int);
```

## Strong typing solutions

The solutions thus far don't deal with strong typing. Perhaps that's desirable. Perhaps not.

To understand what I mean by this, let's first look at literals:

```
say WHAT 1;             # (Int)
say WHAT [1,2];         # (Array)
say WHAT [[1,2],[3,4]]; # (Array)
```

- These values have types determined by their literal constructors.
- The last two are just `Array`s, generic over their elements.

  (The second is *not* an `Array[Int]`, which might be expected. Similarly the last one is *not* an `Array[Array[Int]]`.)

  Current built in Raku literal forms for composite types (arrays and hashes) all construct generic `Array`s which do not constrain the types of their elements.

  See the PR [Introduce `[1,2,3]:Int` syntax #4406](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/4406) for a proposal/PR regarding element typed composite literals and [a related issue I just posted in response to your Q here](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4517) about an alternative and/or complementary approach to that PR. (There have been discussions over the years about this aspect of the type system but it seems like it's time for Rakoons to look at addressing it.)

What if you wanted to build a strongly typed data structure as the value to return from your routine, and to have the return type check that?

---

Here's one way one might build such a strongly typed value:

```
my Array[Array[Int]] $result .= new: Array[Int].new(1,2), Array[Int].new(3,4);
```

Super verbose! But now you could write the following for your sub's return type check and it'll work:

```
subset TArray of Array[Array[Int]] where 0 < .elems == .grep: (Int,Int);

sub fcn(Int $n) of TArray is export(:fcn) {
  my Array[Array[Int]] $result .= new: Array[Int].new(1,2), Array[Int].new(3,4);
}
```

---

Another way to build a strongly typed value is to specify not only the strong typing in a variable's type constraint, but also [*coercion typing*](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#index-entry-Coercion_type) to bridge from a loosely typed value to a strongly typed target.

We keep the exact same `subset` (that establishes the strongly typed target data structure and adds "refinement typing" checks):

```
subset TArray of Array[Array[Int]] where 0 < .elems == .grep: (Int,Int);
```

But instead of using a verbose correct-by-construction initialization value, using full type names and `new`s, we introduce additional coercion typing and then just use ordinary literal syntax:

```
constant TArrayInitialization = TArray(Array[Array[Int]()]());

sub fcn(Int $n) of TArray is export(:fcn) {
  my TArrayInitialization $result = [[1,2],[3,4]];
}
```

(I could have written the `TArrayInitialization` declaration as another `subset`, but it would be a slight overkill to have done so. A `constant` does the job with less fuss.)

Comment: ```
subset TArray where .all == 2;
sub fcn(Int $n) of TArray is export(:fcn) {
    [[1.1, "a"], [3, 4]];
}
```
works but should not.

Comment: @p6steve: I think op just wants a couple of `Int`'s.

Comment: @user3166747 "`subset TArray where .all == 2; sub fcn(Int $n) of TArray is export(:fcn) { [[1.1, "a"], [3, 4]]; }` works but should not." I presume you meant there "should" be **a** way, even if not that particular code. After you wrote your comment I edited my answer to try better present what I understood to be the current possibilities. Raku(do) continues to improve and I hope there'll "soon" be a succinct way to express, in a single named return type, the required combination of strong typing and coercion typing I show in my answer's closing **Strong typing solutions** section.

Answer (score 4):

I gather that the aim is to restrict the type of the inner Array to [Int,Int] ... the closest I can get to this is to declare two subsets, one based on the other...

```
subset IArray where * ~~ [Int, Int];
subset TArray where .all ~~ IArray;
```

Otherwise, the anonymous subset form you use seems to be the briefest, although as @raiph points out you can drop the 'of Array' piece.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to impose this sort of constraint on a function's parameter (rather than its return type) you could do so with something like:

```
sub fcn(@a where {all .map: * ~~ [Int, Int]}) {...}
```

As the other answers have mentioned, there currently isn't great syntax for similarly constraining the return type, but there's a proposal to [add support for similar syntax for return types](https://github.com/Raku/problem-solving/issues/152).  In fact, as mentioned in that issue, someone has volunteered to work on an implementation but hasn't yet made any progress as far as I know.  (And I guess I should know, since I was that volunteer… oops)

So, for now, a subset is the best option – but hopefully the future will have even better ways to write that.